# Why is f-bounded polymorphism im Scala commonly implemented with an upper type bound as well as a self type

Tags: scala, f-bounded-polymorphism

Why is f-bounded polymorphism in Scala commonly implemented with an upper type bound *as well as* a self type like

```scala
trait MyTrait[A <: MyTrait[A]] { self: A =>
  …
}
```

and not simply with *just* a self type like

```scala
trait MyTrait[A] { self: A =>
  …
}
```

The upper type bound in the first example seems to be unnecessary. At least I can't find any benefits of using one. Am I overlooking something here? The type bounds does however stand in the way of usages like

```scala
def func[A](implicit ev: A <:< MyTrait[A]) = ???
```

(of course in this simplistic and contrived example a `func[A <: MyTrait[A]]` would resolve the issue but that might not be possible in a more complex setting)

I found f-bounded polymorphism implemented *with* a type bound in multiple libraries and even in an introductory blog post about the topic (https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) and was wondering if it would be better to omit the type bound in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the idea of `trait MyTrait[A <: MyTrait[A]] { self: A => ... }` is to force `A` to be the type of the current implementation.

If you omit the upper bound, then, aside from `Foo` not being able to do very much with its type parameter (it knows nothing about its members), you can also do things like this, which is not very useful.

```
   trait Foo[A] { self: A => }
   trait Bar 
   class Baz extends Foo[Bar] with Bar
```

Or even just `class Bat extends Foo[Any]`

Comment: I guess that `trait Bar with Foo` is supposed to be `trait Bar extends Foo[Bar]`? That whole construction (including your definition of `Baz`) is also possible _with_ the upper bound and is a known limitation of the expressiveness of f-bounded polymorphism in Scala. The example with the `Any` seems indeed to be a notable difference.
I also don't unterstand what you mean by "Foo not being able to do very much with its type parameter". Do you have an example what `Foo` would be able to do with its type parameter with the upper bound that it can't do without it?

Comment: @mrArkwright no with the upper bound the parameter to `Foo` would have to be a subclass of `Foo`, which `Bar` is not, so `Foo[Bar]` would be impossible.

Comment: @mrArkwright Re. "what Foo can do with upper bound" ... well, I dunno ... `def foo: A = this` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are mistaken. I just compiled those three lines of code _with_ the upper bound (and with `trait Bar extends Foo[Bar]`. Can you please confirm, that this is what you meant? Or ideally edit your answer accordingly.) Please go ahead any try for yourself.

Comment: `def foo: A = this` is also possible without the upper bound. So that's no difference there.

Comment: @mrArkwright Sorry, I wasn't clear. How about `def copy: A`? In general, I'd say if you are having trouble coming up with a use case, you probably don't need f-bounded polymorphism in the first place :)

Comment: What about `def copy: A` wouldn't be possible without the upper bound? I don't have trouble coming up with a use case. `def foo: A = this` is a perfectly fine example of what can be achieved by it. But that wasn't my question.

Comment: @mrArkwright I edited the answer, sorry (what I had there before didn't actually compile)... The whole idea was that `Bar` does _not_ extend `Foo`. Without upper bound for the parameter, you can create instances of `Foo`  (like `Baz`) who `copy` method ends up returning things that are not `Foo`

Comment: @mrArkwright [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GZs4ZVvUSnuNV4y2MW55og) works. [This](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ph7DVurcS9u6ATtgccdwnQ) does not.
By "trouble coming up with usecase" I meant that you are actually asking me to give you examples when `Foo` would need to know that `A` is `Foo` ... If you don't have a use-case like that, you don't need f-bounded polymorphism.

Comment: Oh right, now I see the difference when Bar is not extending Foo. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I feel like you misread my question regarding the examples. Without the upper bound A is still to be known to be a super type of whatever extends Foo. That enables definitions like `def foo: A = this` which is a use case of f-bounded polymorphism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232814/discussion-between-mrarkwright-and-dima).

Comment: @mrArkwright You are missing the point. We don't (only) want it to be a "supertype of whatever extends Foo". We want it to _also_ be a subtype of `Foo`. That's the whole point. Look at the example in the tutorial you mentioned in your answer. Without the upper bound, you can make `Kitty.renamed` return a 'ClawedCreature` or something. It's not useful, you want it to be a `Kitty`.

Comment: Thanks. That was the actual explanation I was looking for!

Comment: I should be noted that even with an upper bound nothing prevents us from defining `Kitty.renamed` to return a `ClawedCreature` if we define `ClawedCreature` to extend `Pet[ClawedCreature]`. So the upper bound does provide some additional safety but doesn't eliminate all fallacies of that sort, which is the aforementioned limitation of f-bounded polymorphism in Scala.

Comment: @mrArkwright yeah, but at least with the upper bound you guarantee that whatever `rename` returns is still a `Pet`

Comment: That's what I meant by _additional safety_.